# Overriding cy.get with a custom command to default to using data-cy?

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to use `data-cy` as much as I can in my code.

It's slightly tedious having to write `cy.get('[data-cy=name]')` all the time.

Is it possible to create a custom command that would by default try and find a data-cy first.

So if I wrote `cy.get('name')` it would try and find `data-cy="name"` on the page, if I used `cy.get('.class')` it would try and find a class with `class` on the page, if I used `cy.get('#id')` it would try and find an id with 'id` on the page?

Basically, I just want `cy.get()` to default to trying to find `data-cy` first and then work as it originally does if I pass in anything else to it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a nifty idea, but you are leaning towards conditional testing if you try to do all-in-one.

I would have a custom command for `data-cy` and stick with `cy.get()` for the other selectors

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('attr', { prevSubject: false }, (attr) => {
  return cy.get(`[data-cy="${attr}"]`)
})

cy.attr('name')
```

Answer (score 1):

Selecting UI elements based on an attribute, such as `data-cy`, is even described in the Cypress best practices section [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Selecting-Elements).

There is also an example on how to create a custom command to have a common way for selecting the elements [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Real-World-Example).

The examples look like:

```
// cypress/support/commands.ts

Cypress.Commands.add('getBySel', (selector, ...args) => {
  return cy.get(`[data-cy=${selector}]`, ...args)
})

Cypress.Commands.add('getBySelLike', (selector, ...args) => {
  return cy.get(`[data-cy*=${selector}]`, ...args)
})
```

The first command looks for an exact `data-cy` attribute match. The second one looks for elements containing a `data-cy` like the provided argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you add [Cypress Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/cypress-testing-library/intro/) to your project you get a bunch of commands around the `data-testid` attribute

> ByTestId  - find by data-testid attribute
>
> - getByTestId
> - queryByTestId
> - getAllByTestId
> - queryAllByTestId
> - findByTestId
> - findAllByTestId

See [Cheatsheet](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/cheatsheet/#queries) for differences.

If you are tired of typing `cy.get('[data-cy=name]')`, then this profusion of selection methods may vex you even more.

The interesting part is the discussion about what selection methods are best for testing.

See [Priority](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#priority)

> Based on the Guiding Principles, your test should resemble how users interact with your code (component, page, etc.) as much as possible.

Interestingly, they place `*ByTestId` at the bottom of the list

> The user cannot see (or hear) these, so this is only recommended for cases where you can't match by role or text or it doesn't make sense (e.g. the text is dynamic).